# How to use inline expression to change displayed content based on other value on ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net

I am working in the aspx file of a page.

I have below in my `asp:Label`'s `Text` property

`<%# Int32.Parse(Eval("Count").ToString()) %>`

What I want to do is check if Count is greater then 5.  If it is, instead of showing the 5 show 1.  I want to do this in the aspx file and not in the code-behind.

EDIT: How would i do this if i wanted to use a variable declared in the <% %> and save the Count value in that variable. Then use if-then on that variable to check it if is greater then 5?

Comment: You can use the ternary operator <%# Int32.Parse(Eval("Count").ToString()) > 5 ? 1 : Int32.Parse(Eval("Count").ToString())  %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%# Int32.Parse(Eval("Count").ToString()) > 5 ? 1 : Int32.Parse(Eval("Count").ToString() %>
```

Use a [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Comment: Thanks.  @mason How would i do this if i wanted to use a variable declared in the <% %> and save the Count value in that variable.  Then use if-then on that variable to check it if is greater then 5?

Comment: @Dust I don't think you can do that within that type of expression within a Label's text attribute. That's why I used the conditional operator. On a side note, if you switch to ASP.NET Web Pages or MVC instead of Web Forms, you can use [Razor syntax](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c)) which makes what you described really easy. So if you find yourself running into that a lot, then perhaps you should switch to tooling that complements your coding style better.

Comment: Thanks.  I only ran into it this time and conditional operator works just fine.  Initially i tried using a separate variable to make syntax little easier to read but was running into issues.